# Javascript based symbolic math

Tags: javascript, math

I want to include in a javascript based application some symbolic math
calculations, like those that are usually done by Mathematica.
For example the user (u)  can enter an algebraic equation, and ask for
it solution for a specified unknown. Output (o) is then returned
Two simple examples:

o: enter an equation:
s: 2*x + 3 = 6
o:  x=1.5

o: enter an equation:
s: a*x + b = c
o: solve for?
s: x
o: x=(c-b)/a.

Does anyone know if there a JS based library for this (free or
commercially available)?

Comment: this is generally not this type of research site.  you should post what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: google for "javascript symbolic math" returns [this library](https://github.com/jamesmclellan/Symbolic-Math-Library-for-Javascript), [this other library](http://code.google.com/p/smath/wiki/smathJavaScriptAPI), [this duplicate question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870215/are-there-any-somewhat-advanced-mathematics-javascript-libraries), etc.

Comment: sorry randy, while you may want that to be true, that isn't the case. There is plenty of evidence of people asking for help finding libraries... Also the other posts don't cover symbolic algebra solutions akin to Mathematica, where a formula is presented and solved.  The answer from the duplicate post, as far as I can tell is a simple parser for algebra only, while there is no lack of vector based solutions. The question is specific to mathematica based functionality that may exist in JS. Thanks for the direction though. You might want to post it as an answer