# Javascript mathematical library

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I'm working on a project in which users define formulas that are to be executed against user inputs.

On the UI side, a user would, for example, input the value for varA, and varB. The javascript code is supposed to pick up these two values, inject them in a formula like so:

```
varA + varB ** (1/2.0)
```

And then return the result.

The problem I'm facing is that some operations (like the `**` exemplified above) don't map directly into javascript, having to somehow translate these formulas to it. Is there any library that implements this kind of stuff that I can use?

Edit: I found [this](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval), which does exactly what I need (and incorporates `^` instead of `**`, which is a `replace` away.)

Any better ones?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what is `**` supposed to do?

Comment: In ruby at least, is `**` an exponent operation `a ** 2` is a squared.

Comment: from my knowledge I don't think so.. but you could always do it by functions aka the function `squared` that will square the number you put into it..

Comment: also if you searched up this (javascript mathematics library) on google you get quite a lot of good results.. also some on SO, so heres a few links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870215/are-there-any-somewhat-advanced-mathematics-javascript-libraries   https://github.com/patrickroberts/Javascript-Complex-Math-Library

Comment: Check this out: http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a parser library or write your own.

Comment: I did! Check the edit. Great parsing library that did exactly what I wanted :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the expression parser from the math.js library. Uses a `^` character for power too though.

http://mathjs.org

Example usage:

```
var parser = math.parser();
parser.eval('a = 1.2 / (2.3 + 0.7)');   // 0.4
parser.eval('2 * a');                   // 0.8
parser.eval('5.08 cm in inch');         // 2 inch
parser.eval('sin(45 deg) ^ 2');         // 0.5
parser.eval('9 / 3 + 2i');              // 3 + 2i
parser.eval('det([-1, 2; 3, 1])');      // -7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ES6](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-exponentiation-operator) you can do the following:

```
let varA = 1
let varB = 5
const answer = varA + varB ** (1 / 2.0)
```

```js
let varA = 1
let varB = 5
const answer = varA + varB ** (1 / 2.0)
const output = `${varA} + ${varB} ** (1 / 2.0) =\n${answer}`
document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = output
```

```css
.output {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<pre class="output"></pre>
```